# In Graph Neural Network is Message Passing Step Agnostic of Output Values during Training?

Tags: backpropagation, graph-neural-networks, representation-learning

So Graph Neural Networks is about representation learning where initially representation of graph is learned in the form of node embeddings. My question is: Are the output values back propagated and influence learned node embeddings? The [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.05055) I read seems to not account for output being backpropogated so that embeddings get learned. So does that mean learning node embeddings is agnostic of output values during training?